# Geometric understanding of "Pauli vector" determinant?

Tags: representation-theory, determinant, quadratic-forms, quaternions, clifford-algebras

If we define the [Pauli matrices](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pauli_matrices) as

$$\sigma_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\sigma_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\sigma_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\ 
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\sigma_3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix},$$

and define the vector space isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb R^{1,3}\ni(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)\mapsto\sum_{\mu=0}^3 x^\mu\sigma_\mu\in M_2(\mathbb C)$, then it is straightforward to compute that $\det\phi(x)=(x^0)^2-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2-(x^3)^2=:Q(x),$ where $Q$ is the standard quadratic form on $\mathbb R^{1,3}$. **I'm looking for a coordinate-free, geometric understanding of this fact.**

To illustrate what I'm looking for, consider the real algebra generated by the Pauli matrices, which is isomorphic to the Clifford algebra over $\mathbb R^3$ and also the [biquaternions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Biquaternion) $\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb H$. Multiplying the matrices $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}$ by $i$, along with the same $\sigma_0$, gives a representation of $\mathbb H$, whose elements act naturally on $\mathbb H$ (from the left, say) before choosing a matrix representation. I discuss in the comments to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4624040/477746) how we can understand $\det (q)=|q|^2$ as a geometric consequence of quaternion multiplication.

But unlike $\mathbb H$, the Pauli matrices do not form a subalgebra of $\text{Cl}_{3,0}(\mathbb R)\simeq\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb H$, so it is harder to find a "natural" two-dimensional complex vector space on which these matrices act, let alone finding a geometric picture of the action of these matrices on such a space.

Comment: One way or another this is going to boil down to the exceptional isomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{C}) \cong Spin(3, 1)$ but I'm not sure what the details look like exactly.

Comment: This is almost certainly related to the fact that your $\psi$ embeds a vector as a *paravector* of $\mathrm{Cl}_{3,0}(\mathbb R)$, and these paravectors descend naturally from vectors in $\mathrm{Cl}_{1,3}(\mathbb R)$. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536536/why-is-it-that-we-can-represent-vectors-using-the-even-part-of-the-clifford-alge/4541121#4541121) for more on paravectors.